# I am trying to read numbers from a file

Tags: c++, eof

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int v[101];

int main()
{
int max=0; int a,i;
ifstream f("bac.in");
ofstream g("bac.out");

while(!EOF(f))
{
    f >> a;
    while(a>10)
      if(a%10!=0 && (a/10)%10!=0)  v[a%100]++;
    a/=10;
}
for(i=10;i<=99;i++) if(v[i]>max) max=v[i];
for(i=10;i<=99;i++) if(v[i]==max) g<<i;

}
```

I get the error **14 | error: '-1' cannot be used as a function**
If i use eof instead of EOF i get the error **'eof' was not included in this scope** but i have already included **cstudio** or **studio.h**
What should i change?

Comment: You [shouldn't](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong) be using EOF as the condition anyway.

Comment: ***cstudio***, ***studio.h*** ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EOF` is not a function, it's a constant. However, you shouldn't be using `eof` to find the end of file anyway ([here is why](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/335858)).

Put reading itself into loop header, like this:

```
while(f >> a) {
    while(a>10)
      if(a%10!=0 && (a/10)%10!=0)  v[a%100]++;
    a/=10;
}
```

The reason this works is that `f >> a`, which returns `istream`, has a conversion operator<sup>*</sup> which allows the expression to be used as a condition. When the read is successful, the resultant condition evaluates to `true`; otherwise, it's `false`.

<sup>*</sup> The details of the conversion are different in C++98 and C++11/14, but the expression remains valid regardless of the C++ standard.

Comment: @CiobyAndrei You are welcome! If the problem is solved, consider accepting the answer by clicking the grey check mark next to it. This would let others know that you are no longer actively looking for an improved solution, and earn you a new badge on Stack Overflow.